# Javascript dynamic conditional onclick event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET gridview, with the code below (modified from another stackoverflow question) to make the row clickable.

```
e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.gvPricingGrid, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
```

I also have a button that, when clicked, flips a boolean held in the session (accessed through a code-behind property), and makes visible some textboxes in each row for updating the row. The property is called IsEditingProperty

What I want is for the onclick to work as it does now when IsEditingProperty = False, but do nothing when the property = True. I have tried the below, but the property is evaluated at render, rather than when the click actually occurs.

```
e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = "if (""<% IsEditingProperty() %>"") " & Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.gvPricingGrid, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
```

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: this is a mess of code. Did you try thinking in a function?

Comment: I will spend some time seeing about making it a function tomorrow. I'd not done that, and I have some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dealing with this by realizing that rowCreated happens on postback simply adding the check against the property there.